# deep copy extension of List<T> in dart

Tags: dart

I was trying to make a deep copy of List in Dart using the extension method. But I am getting an error:

```
The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.
```

code:

```
extension ListExtensions<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> get shallowClone {
    List<T> res = [];
    for (var elem in this) {
      if (elem is List<dynamic>) {
        res.add(elem.shallowClone);
      }
      else {
        res.add(elem);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach which also copies the type arguments of the lists:

```dart
extension ListClone<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> clone() {
    var copy = this.toList();
    List<Object?> untypedCopy = copy;
    for (var i = 0; i < untypedCopy.length; i++) {
      var element = untypedCopy[i];
      if (element is List) {
        untypedCopy[i] = element.clone();
      }
    }
    return copy;
  }
}
```

This creates a new list of the *same element type* as the original (using `toList` which uses the actual type).
Then it checks each element for being a list, and clones it if that's the case. Then the clone is assigned back using unsound covariance to make it a run-time type check, which should succeed since the clone has the same type as the original element.

Example:

```dart
// List<List<List<int>>> containing List<List<int>> containing List<int>
var list = [[[1]]];

// Ditto!
var clone = list.clone();
```